# Javascript code for serial img loading

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I want a javascript code with which i can load an image which is named for every day/month/year. in a serial
i have the following code :

```
var year = new Array();
year = ["08", "09", "10", "11"];

var month = new Array();
month = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JULY", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];

var date = new Array();
date = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"];

var ims = "";
for (var x in year) {
 for (var y in month) {
  for (var z in date) {
   ims += "<im src=screencover/img/" + date[z] + "" + month[y] + "20" + year[0] + ".png>";
  }
 }
}
document.write(ims);
```

Comment: Why do you initialize your arrays with empty array objects before replacing them with new (populated) arrays?

Comment: The obvious bug is `year[0]`, which should be `year[x]`. The more basic bug is using `for..in` to loop through arrays.

Comment: My question is how do i load the images with day/month/year.png without creating extra imgs for days which are not in a month for example it created 31 days in feb instead of 28/29 or 31 days in nov instead of 30thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built-in Date object:

```
function getFullYearArray(year) {
    var dates = [new Date(year, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)],
        oneday = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    for (var i = 0; i < 364; i++) {
        dates.push( new Date(dates[i].getTime() + oneday) );
    }
    // leap years, if last day is december 30, add one
    if ( dates[i].getDate() == 30 ) {
        dates.push( new Date(dates[i].getTime() + oneday) );
    }
    return dates;
}

// usage
y08 = getFullYearArray(2008);
for (var i = 0, l = y08.length, date; i < l; i++) {
    date = y08[i];
    console.log( date.toDateString() );
}
```

You will have to parse the date string for the values to build your image src string, but this should get you started.

**Edit**

I went ahead and built out the string:

```
function getFullYearArray(year) {
    var dates = [new Date(year, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)],
        oneday = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    for (var i = 0; i < 364; i++) {
        dates.push( new Date(dates[i].getTime() + oneday) );
    }
    // leap years, if last day is december 30, add one
    if ( dates[i].getDate() == 30 ) {
        dates.push( new Date(dates[i].getTime() + oneday) );
    }
    return dates;
}

// usage
var ims = "",
    y08 = getFullYearArray(2008);
for (var i = 0, l = y08.length, date, m, d, y; i < l; i++) {
    date = y08[i].toDateString();
    d = date.substring(8, 10);
    m = date.substring(4, 7).toUpperCase();
    y = date.substring(11, 15);

    ims += "<img src=\"screencover/img/" + d + m + y + ".png\">\n";
}

console.log(ims);
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: now i get it :)

Try something this:

```
function nrpad(number, length) {
  var str = '' + number;
  while (str.length < length) {
      str = '0' + str;
  }
  return str;
}
var end_date = new Date(2011, 12, 1).getTime();
var start_date = new Date(2008, 1, 1).getTime();

var step = 86400000; // 1 day in msec
for(var ts = start_date; ts <= end_date; ts += step){
  var d = new Date(ts);
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'screencover/img/' + nrpad(d.getDay(),2) + nrpad(d.getMonth(),2) + nrpad(d.getFullYear(),2) + '.png';
  //console.log(img.src);
}
```

but you will have to rename your files like 'DDMMYYYY.png' (use a numeric month) if you use that example.

Comment: thanks for your reply Florian Fida, my code works fine, the problem is it creates imgs for the days which are not in a month for example it creates 31 days in feb or 30 in nov. thats the problem

Comment: Create another array of 'days per month'

Comment: edited my answer... you can use js Date object to generate valid dates.

Comment: Did you really choose the other example as your answer?
Twice as much Date objects created and the need to use document.write...
And i wouldn't recomend formatting a date like this...
When you dig deeper into js, is some point in the future, you'll think about me :)

Comment: I take offense! For a period of 4 years, my answer only creates 2 more Date objects than yours, and the output actually conforms to the requirements stated in the question.